# Keep vertical scroll position when clicking horizontal carousel button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a long page with lots of patient data inside an accordion container.  At the top of the page there is a carousel with the 7 days of the week.  If you click on the left or right arrow, either the previous or following week will show, which in turn, will show the applicable data below in the accordion.

What I need to do is when a user clicks on the left or right arrow, hold the page position on the current accordion section, but still allow the data to be updated.  The data currently updates, but the container location may change.  That particular container may not have data for one week, but the next week may have data.

I would like to click the arrow and still show the previous container heading.

Ex. I'm on the Hematology container and I click on the right arrow.  I want the Hematology container to still be in view, even if there is no content inside.

Here is a screenshot of my page with the carousel and containers.
[image]

I know how to do this with anchor tags when dealing with links to different pages, but this is a bit different.

This project uses Angular to asynchronously get the new data for the containers.  You can see it below.  Thanks

**Here is my code for the carousel:**

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide russ" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"></div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href=".russ" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href=".russ" role="button" data-slide="next" onclick="stopVerticalScrolling()">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**My first crack at this:**

```
<script>
    function stopVerticalScrolling() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("html").scrollTop(scroll);

        //javascript: alert($(window).scrollTop());
    }
</script>
```

**AngularJS Code:**

```
function get_sticky_popup_data(timeline, patientMRN, patientSiteid, start, end) {
    $http
    .get('/API/data/patientdetails/Titlebar/get_admission_data/' + patientSiteid + '?MRN=' + patientMRN)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.carouseldata = data;
        build_sticky_table(timeline, $scope.carouseldata, start, end);
        var carouselItemTop = $('.displayTableContainer').position();
        $('.displayTableContainer').attr('data-offset-top', carouselItemTop.top);
    }).error(function(e) {
        console.log('error in Ajax call get_admission_data: ' + e.message);
    });
}

function build_sticky_table(timeline, items, start, end) {

    var startDate = new Date(start.toString());
    var endDate = new Date(end.toString());
    var dtRotate = new Date(startDate);
    var firstWeeksDataObject = new Array(7);

    var datediff = ((endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + 1;

    var weeks = (datediff % 7 === 0 ? parseInt((datediff / 7)) + 1 : parseInt((datediff / 7))); // you need this many tables

    $('.item').remove();

    items.push({
        'admit': timeline.admission_range_start,
        'datetime': timeline.event_start_date,
        'diagnosis': '',
        'discharge': timeline.admission_range_end,
        'location': timeline.location,
        'room_bed': timeline.roombed
    });

    var isActive = false;
    var starting_month_from_query_string = $('#workflow_header_month').val();
    var starting_year_from_query_string = $('#workflow_header_year').val();
    var match_weekly_data_from_query_string_month_and_year = false;
    var previous_match_found = false;
    var current_event_start_date = timeline.event_start_date;

    if (starting_month_from_query_string !== "0" && starting_year_from_query_string !== "0") {
        match_weekly_data_from_query_string_month_and_year = true;
    }


    for (var i = 0; i <= weeks; i++) {

        var name = 'stickytbl' + i.toString();
        $('.carousel-inner').append(buildtable(name, i)); //inserts a new table
        var hcells = $('#' + name + ' > thead > tr > td');
        var brows = $('#' + name + ' > tbody> tr');
        $.each(hcells, function (index, item) {
            if (index > 0) {
                var cell = $(brows[0]).children('td');
                var cell2 = $(brows[1]).children('td');
                var cell3 = $(brows[2]).children('td');

                //set the column data
                var currentColumnHeaderDate = dtRotate.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + dtRotate.getDate() + '/' + dtRotate.getFullYear();
                var currentColumnHeaderDateWithTime = new Date(currentColumnHeaderDate.toString() + ' 23:59:59');
                firstWeeksDataObject[index] = currentColumnHeaderDate;

                $(item).text((dtRotate.getMonth()) + 1 + '/' + dtRotate.getDate() + '/' + dtRotate.getFullYear());
                //set the row data
                if (dtRotate <= currentColumnHeaderDateWithTime) {
                    var arrayReturn = getDaysData(items, start, end, dtRotate, currentColumnHeaderDate);
                    //set table row data
                    $(cell[index]).html(arrayReturn[0]);
                    $(cell2[index]).html(arrayReturn[1]);
                    $(cell3[index]).html(arrayReturn[2]);
                }
                //increment the date
                dtRotate.setDate(dtRotate.getDate() + 1);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the new data when you click to another week, an AJAX request? How does the container location change specifically? Can you provide a more complete code sample that shows the problem?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS.  I've added the code that populates the containers.  Thanks